# How to write a program in python which prints the fist letter of every word of the input string without using built-in fuctions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

```
sen=input ("Enter a sentence: ")
index=0

for i in sen:
   if i<=len(sen):
       if sen[i]!=' ':
           print(sen[i])
exit()
```

Comment: `for i in sen:` does not give a loop index so `if i<=len(sen):` will not work since you'll be trying to compare a string to an integer (given by `len()`)

Comment: sir, I am new to python, so making mistakes. Please help me to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can just iterate trought the string, check for Spaces and then take the Charakter after the space:

```
def main(string):
    count = 0
    output = []
    for _ in string:
        if string[count] == ' ':
            output.append(string[count + 1])
        count += 1
    return output
```